# Pick the latest folder from Array of folders where folder name has the date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have below list of folder paths

```
var allLeafDirPaths= Array(
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20200306/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20200318/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20200319/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20200504/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20201020/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20210302/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20220215/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20220216/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20220223/",
"abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20220301/"
)
```

I want to pick the latest folder as you can see it should be below one generated on `01-Mar-2022`

```
abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20220301/"
```

I tried below code that works. But my code may not be that good. Can we do this in any other better way?

```
for(path <- allLeafDirPaths){  
  pathDatesString +:= path.substring(path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf("/")).lastIndexOf("/")+1,path.length()-1)
  pathDatesInt = pathDatesString.map(_.toInt)
  maxPathDatesInt = pathDatesInt.reduceLeft(_ max _)
  
  if(path.contains("/".concat(maxPathDatesInt.toString).concat("/"))){
     finalPath = path
  }
}
finalPathArray = Array("")
finalPathArray +:= finalPath
println("final path is")
println(finalPathArray.mkString("\n"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`maxBy` or `maxByOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#maxBy%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering%5BB%5D):A) and maybe a Regex instead of the `indexOf` stuff.

```scala
val DatePattern = ".*/(\\d+)/$".r
def pathToDate(path: String): Option[Int] = path match {
  case DatePattern(rawDate) => Some(rawDate.toInt)
  case _ => None
}

allLeafDirPaths.maxBy(pathToDate)
// returns "abfss://cont@mystorage.dfs.core.windows.net/customer/Full/20220301/"
```

**Explanation**

`maxBy` finds the max from the sequence based on a "measurement function", e.g. you want to measure your paths by a date value, so you provide the `pathToDate` method as your measurement function.

Scala provides a handy [`Regex`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html) class and a convenience [`.r`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/StringOps.html#r:scala.util.matching.Regex) method on String (implicitly via StringOps) that lets you construct a Regex from a String pattern. Regex implements `unapplySeq(s: CharSequence)`, which lets it work as an "extractor object" in a `match/case` block.